# Azure SQL Database Occasionally Slow to COnnect

Tags: azure

I have been given a task of combatting an occasional slowness starting up an Azure web app. The web app calls makes seven separate Azure API controller calls that each connect to an Azure SQL Server in order to run stored procedures. The application insights show that these calls take less than 250ms 90 percent of the time but will take 7-15 seconds at other times. Adding logging shows the OpenConnection statement accounts for all of the delay.

```
        date1 = DateTime.Now;
        _dbContext.Database.OpenConnection();
        date2 = DateTime.Now;
        if (_logger != null)
        {

            interval = date2 - date1;
            _logger.LogDebug(string.Format("GetUserDetails Opened Connection {0:N0}", interval.TotalMilliseconds));
        }
```

I added a min pool size and max pool size of 200 to the connection string. It did not help and the application insights does not show more than 100 connections at a time. Profiling the Azure SQL Server shows the Audit logout with a similar delay when connecting.

Where else should I look to find a cause for this occasional delay in creating connections?

Thanks in advance,
Hank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With performance, it could be a bunch of things. I can provide a couple of things that you could check.

1. Is it always the Xth iteration/invocation etc. that is causing the delay ? In that case, see if you have any locks etc. due to the previous queries, etc.
2. If you are connecting to Managed instance, [check your connection policy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/connection-types-overview). Setting it to proxy can also lead to throttling when there is high network load. (or if you are connecting and querying crazy fast let's say in a loop, etc.)
3. This is something simple, but make sure you are using a connecting string rather than specifying the connection details in code every time. Connection pooling features only kick in when using a connection string. (Could also explain why you have 100 connections)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Issues 1 & 3 do not apply but we do have the proxy connection which I will take aim at.